# Read function to get samples of hand written numbers for logistic regresion

Tags: python, logistic-regression, gradient-descent

I have and algorithm for logistic regresion with gradient descent and mini batch:

```
from scipy.special import expit    

def sigmoide(x):
    return expit(x)

class RegresionLogisticaMiniBatch():

    def __init__(self,clases=[0,1],normalizacion=False,
                  rate=0.1,rate_decay=False,batch_tam=64):
    
        self.clases = clases;
        self.rate = rate;
        self.normalizacion = normalizacion;
        self.rate_decay = rate_decay;
        self.batch_tam = batch_tam;
        self.pesos = None
        self.media = None
        self.desviacion = None


    def entrena(self, X, y, n_epochs, reiniciar_pesos=False, pesos_iniciales=None):
        self.X = X
        self.y = y
        self.n_epochs = n_epochs
        
        if reiniciar_pesos or self.pesos is None:
            #self.pesos = pesos_iniciales if pesos_iniciales is not None else np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=X.shape[1])
            self.pesos = pesos_iniciales if pesos_iniciales is not None else np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=X.shape[1]) if len(X.shape) > 1 else np.random.uniform(-1, 1)

        if self.normalizacion:
            self.media = np.mean(X, axis=0)
            self.desviacion = np.std(X, axis=0)
            X = (X - self.media) / self.desviacion

        indices = np.random.permutation(len(X))
        X_shuffled = X[indices]
        y_shuffled = y[indices]
        for j in range(n_epochs):
            for i in range(0, len(X), self.batch_tam):
                batch_X = X_shuffled[i:i + self.batch_tam]
                batch_y = y_shuffled[i:i + self.batch_tam]
            
                # Compute logistic function (sigmoid)
                z = np.dot(batch_X, self.pesos)
                y_pred = sigmoide(z)

                # Compute gradient
                error = batch_y - y_pred
                gradiente = np.dot(batch_X.T, error) / len(batch_X)

                # Update weights
                self.pesos += self.rate * gradiente

    def clasifica_prob(self, ejemplo):
        if self.pesos is None:
            raise ClasificadorNoEntrenado("El clasificador no ha sido entrenado")

        if self.normalizacion:
            ejemplo = (ejemplo - self.media) / self.desviacion

        probabilidad = sigmoide(np.dot(ejemplo, self.pesos))
        if probabilidad >= 0.5:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

     
    def clasifica(self,ejemplo):
        probabilidad = self.clasifica_prob(ejemplo)
        return probabilidad
```

Then, i have another algorithm to implement multi class in the previous one using One vs Rest technique (I do not get a good score with this algorithm, I do not know why):

```
from scipy.special import softmax

class RL_OvR():

     def __init__(self,clases,rate=0.1,rate_decay=False,batch_tam=64):

        self.clases = clases
        self.rate = rate
        self.rate_decay = rate_decay
        self.batch_tam = batch_tam
        self.clasificadores = {}


     def entrena(self,X,y,n_epochs):
         
        self.X = X
        self.y = y
        self.n_epochs = n_epochs
        self.classifiers = {}

        for clase in self.clases:
            # Convertir el problema de múltiples clases en un problema de dos clases
            binary_y = np.where(y == clase, 1, 0)
            classifier = RegresionLogisticaMiniBatch(clases=[0, 1],
                                                     rate=self.rate,
                                                     rate_decay=self.rate_decay,
                                                     batch_tam=self.batch_tam)
            classifier.entrena(X, binary_y, n_epochs)
            self.classifiers[clase] = classifier



     def clasifica(self,ejemplo):
         
        probabilidades = []

        for classifier in self.classifiers.values():
            probabilidad = classifier.clasifica_prob(ejemplo)
            probabilidades.append(probabilidad)

        probabilidades = softmax(probabilidades)
        clase_predicha = np.argmax(probabilidades)
        return clase_predicha
```

Finally, I want to use this algorithm to predict hand written numbers, I have a text file with the number images with this format:

```
                            
                            
                            
                            
                            
                            
             ++###+         
             ######+        
            +######+        
            ##+++##+        
           +#+  +##+        
           +##++###+        
           +#######+        
           +#######+        
            +##+###         
              ++##+         
              +##+          
              ###+          
            +###+           
            +##+            
           +##+             
          +##+              
         +##+               
         ##+                
        +#+                 
        +#+                 
                            
                            
                            
                            
                            
              +#++          
             +####+         
           ++######         
           +###+++#         
          +###+  +#+        
          +###   +##        
         +###+    ##+       
         +##+     +#+       
         ###      +#+       
        +##+      +##+      
        +##       +##+      
        +#+       +##+      
        +#+       +##       
        +#+       +#+       
        +##+     +##+       
         ###+    +##+       
         +####++###++       
         +#########         
          ++#######         
            +###+++
```

So I developed a function to read these numbers and get the samples:

```
def cargar_imagenes(ruta_archivo):
    with open(ruta_archivo, 'r') as archivo:
        lineas = archivo.readlines()
        imagenes = []
        aux = 0
        lista_imagenes = []
        for linea in lineas:
            if linea.strip() == '':
                if aux > 0:
                    lista_imagenes.append(imagenes)
                    imagenes = []
                    aux = 0
            else:
                imagen = [1 if pixel == '#' else 0 for pixel in linea.strip()]
                imagenes.extend(np.array(imagen, dtype=int))
                aux += 1
        if aux > 0:
            lista_imagenes.append(np.array(imagenes))
        return np.array(lista_imagenes, dtype=object)
```

Also I have a function to read the clasifications of these numbers:

```
def cargar_clasificaciones(ruta_archivo):
    with open(ruta_archivo, 'r') as archivo:
        lineas = archivo.readlines()
        clasificaciones = [int(linea.rstrip()) for linea in lineas]
        return np.array(clasificaciones)
```

But, when I try to do the fit with the data:

```
clases = list(range(10))  # Clases del 0 al 9
lr_digitos = RL_OvR(clases, rate=0.001, batch_tam=20)
lr_digitos.entrena(X_entrenamiento, y_entrenamiento, n_epochs=1000)
```

I get this error, and I do not know how to fix it:

> TypeError: ufunc 'expit' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

I need to read the numbers samples correctly to get the predictions with the OvR regressor.